# Apple Connect: Even with the required icon of size 512x512@2x px, I receive a "Missing required icon"

Tags: xcode, macos, store

Note: I read all the previous posts on this topic!

Context:

- Mac Application
- Xcode 9.4.1
- Archiving to submit the app

I followed the documentation to provide an icon picture for the App Store here: https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/dev4b0ebb1bb?sub=dev3c7018a67.

[image: "For macOS apps, drag the App Store icon to the Mac 512pt 2x well in the AppIcon image set."]

So I provided the 512x512@2x pt picture file for the AppIcon entity of the Assets.xcassets in my project.

But I received a mail from Apple Connect saying:

> Missing required icon - The asset catalog in the application bundle
>   does not contain an icon of size 512x512@2x px. For further
>   assistance, see the Apple Human Interface Guidelines at
>   https://developer.apple.com/macos/human-interface-guidelines/icons-and-images/app-icon

The provided link didn't help me.

Reading every post speaking of that on StackOverflow, I tried many things:

- recreate my 1024x1024 icon png picture
- providing jpg
- changing the name of icon picture file
- checking that icon picture files were in xcassets
- checking "Contents.json" file are not wrong
- recreating the AppIcon entity in the xcassets
- provide from 256 to 512 2x AppIcon spots
- changing the name of my app

About 20 different attempts without success. Apple Connect is still refusing my submission with the same message.

Any idea?

Comment: did you check the app bundle to make sure they are there?

Comment: Considering the fact you tried so many different things I don't think it's a solution, but I had issues with this as well. I am really annoyed that you need the same actual icon size multiple times (1024@1x and 512@2x). I usually create one icon per size (2048 down to 16) and drag them to where the actual size is required (the 1024 once for 1024@1x and once for 512@2x)

Comment: I check the xcassets bundle the check if pictures were there. They were. I also check the "contents.json" file in the folder representing the AppIcon entity. Nothing looking wrong.

Comment: Your right Julian, that was the solution

Answer (score 1):

The solution was:

> Provide each AppIcon size spot with icon picture files

I didn't do that as the documentation (as screenshot exposes it) put me in a wrong way as it doesn't show the AppIcon entity with all spot provided.